# Can anyone here explain Ext.ComponentQuery.query('what here comes?')[0] briefly?

Tags: android, checkbox, sencha-touch-2

Hello friends I am stuck at a point in sencha touch 2.0.I am creating a screen in my app in which i need to get the checkbox values(checked or unchecked). i am referring [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Checkbox) example from sencha documentation,but i am unable to understand how to use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('what here comes?')[0].

**EDIT**

here's my code:-

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.groupList',{
    extend : 'Ext.navigation.View',
    requires: ['Ext.field.Search', 'Ext.TitleBar'],
    alias: "widget.groupList",
    itemId: "gList",
    initialize: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments),
        var checkBox = {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
              name : 'all',
            //  label: 'All',
              value: 'all',
              lableWidth: "0",
              width: 1,
              padding: '0 0 15 30',
              checked: false
        };

        var sendBtn = {
                itemId: 'sendBtn',
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Send',
                ui: 'action',
                handler: function() {
                    var check = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('navigationview')[0],
                        values = check.getValues();

                    Ext.Msg.alert(null,
                        "Selected All: " + ((values.all) ? "yes" : "no")

                    );
                }     
        };

        var topToolbar = {
            xtype : "toolbar",
            title : "Groups",
            docked : "top",
            items: [
                    checkBox,
                    {xtype: 'spacer'},      
                  //  searchBtn, 
                    sendBtn
            ],
        };
        var list = {
                xtype: "grlist",
                store: Ext.getStore("grStore")
        };

        this.add([list,topToolbar]);
    },

    config: {
        navigationBar: {
            hidden: true,
        },
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error:-

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'check.getValues' [undefined] is not a function. at
 file:///android_asset/www/app/view/group_list.js
```

So please make me understand how Ext.ComponentQuery works with some sample code or tutorial.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Show us your code, preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: i added code snippet go through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ext.ComponentQuery` accepts 3 types of parameters:

- `xtype`, eg: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('navigationview')`
- `id`, eg: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('my-nav-view-id')`
- `attributes`, eg: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('navigationview[name="my nav view"]')`

No matter which type the param is of, `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()` always returns an array of matched components. In the example, they add `[0]` because it's assured that the result array contains only 1 item.

In your code, it seems that you tried to query a component of xtype `navigationview`, this kind of component does NOT have `getValues` methods (which is only available to `Ext.form.Panel` and derived classes). So if you want to retrieve the values, you have to use queries like this:

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkboxfield')[0]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: if getValues() method is not there in navigatiobview how can i get the value of the checkbox?

Comment: i have understand what you have told but the thing is i dont understand how to proceed after Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkboxfield')[0].Please provide me some code.

Comment: `var check = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkboxfield')[0],
                        value = check.getValue();` - does it work?

Comment: ok its working but one thing is happening here that weather i check the checkbox or not it only showing in dialog box is "Selected all:no"

Comment: `console.log(value)`, what did you get?

Comment: ok buddy i made it working with ur help.i put var check = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#all')[0] and it worked perfectly('all' is the itemId of checkbox).Thanx.

Comment: hey buddy is there any possibility to get the value of checkbox added in itemTpl.I have the following itemTpl.How can i get its values?                                                        itemTpl: '<input type="checkbox" enabled="enabled" value="open" id="status" name="comment_status" <tpl if="active">checked="checked"</tpl> /> {groupName}',

Comment: use `Ext.get()` to access your element

Comment: Hey buddy i have no idea how to use Ext.get(),can show me some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Ext.ComponentQuery documentation is [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)...

It should not be used in this example.
This code would be more resilent and ridiculously faster as wouldn't use a global search method.

```
var sendBtn = {
            itemId: 'sendBtn',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Send',
            ui: 'action',
            scope: this,
            handler: function() {
                var check = this.down('#checkboxfield'),
                values = check.getValue();
                Ext.Msg.alert(null,
                    "Selected All: " + ((values.all) ? "yes" : "no")
                );
            }     
    };
```

Also I've corrected the code example, the method is getValue()

**Note:**
I know that this answer is so out of date it's not relevent, however the accepted method is encouraging the use of Ext.ComponentQuery where it's not needed which is simply awful code and has logical code presuming that ui will remain in the same set format.